# How to write WinForms code that auto-scales to system font and dpi settings?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, dpi

**Intro:** There's a lot of comments out there that say "WinForms doesn't auto-scale to DPI/font settings well; switch to WPF." However, I think that is based on .NET 1.1; it appears they actually did a pretty good job of implementing auto-scaling in .NET 2.0. At least based on our research and testing so far. However, if some of you out there know better, we'd love to hear from you. <sup>(Please don't bother arguing we should switch to WPF... that's not an option right now.)</sup>

#### Questions:

- What in WinForms does NOT auto-scale properly and therefore should be avoided?
- What design guidelines should programmers follow when writing WinForms code such that it will auto-scale well?

#### Design Guidelines we have identified so far:

See [community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29766847/1730559) below.

Are any of those incorrect or inadequate? Any other guidelines we should adopt? Are there any other patterns that need to be avoided? Any other guidance on this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 164):

###Controls which do not support scaling properly:

- `Label` with `AutoSize = False` and `Font` inherited. Explicitly set `Font` on the control so it appears in bold in the Properties window.
- `ListView` column widths don't scale. Override the form's `ScaleControl` to do it instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36974138/1318499)
- `SplitContainer`'s `Panel1MinSize`, `Panel2MinSize` and `SplitterDistance` properties
- `TextBox` with `MultiLine = True` and `Font` inherited. Explicitly set `Font` on the control so it appears in bold in the Properties window.
- `ToolStripButton`'s image. In the form's constructor:
- Set `ToolStrip.AutoSize = False`
- Set `ToolStrip.ImageScalingSize` according to `CreateGraphics.DpiX` and `.DpiY`
- Set `ToolStrip.AutoSize = True` if needed.
- `PictureBox.SizeMode` must be set to Zoom or StretchImage.

Sometimes `AutoSize` can be left at `True` but sometimes it fails to resize without those steps. Works without that changes with [.NET Framework 4.5.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-2/) and `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing`.

- `TreeView`'s images. Set `ImageList.ImageSize` according to `CreateGraphics.DpiX` and `.DpiY`. For [`StateImageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.stateimagelist?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_TreeView_StateImageList), works without that changes with [.NET Framework 4.5.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#What%27s%20new%20in%20the%20.NET%20Framework%204.5.1) and `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing`.
- `Form`'s size. Scale fixed size `Form`'s manually after creation.

###Design Guidelines:

- All ContainerControls must be set to the same `AutoScaleMode = Font`.
  (Font will handle both DPI changes and changes to the system font
  size setting; DPI will only handle DPI changes, not changes to the
  system font size setting.)
- All ContainerControls must also be set with the same `AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);`, assuming 96dpi (see the next bullet) and default Font of MS Sans Serif (see the bullet two down). That is auto-added by the designer
  based on the DPI you open the designer in... but was missing from
  many of our oldest designer files.  Perhaps Visual Studio .NET (the
  version before VS 2005) was not adding that in properly.
- Do all your designer work in 96dpi (we might be able to switch to
  120dpi; but the wisdom on the internet says to stick to 96dpi;
  experimentation is in order there; by design, it shouldn't matter as it just changes the `AutoScaleDimensions` line that the designer inserts).
  To set Visual Studio to run at a virtual 96dpi on a high-resolution display,
  find its .exe file, right-click to edit properties, and under Compatibility
  select "Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: System".
- Be sure you never set the Font at the container level... only on the
  leaf controls OR in the constructor of your most base Form if you want an application-wide default Font other than MS Sans Serif. (Setting the Font on a Container seems to turn off
  the auto-scaling of that container because it alphabetically comes after the setting of AutoScaleMode and AutoScaleDimensions settings.)  NOTE that if you do change the Font in your most base Form's constructor, that will cause your AutoScaleDimensions to compute differently than 6x13; in particular, if you change to Segoe UI (the Win 10 default font), then it will be 7x15... you will need to touch every Form in the Designer so that it can recompute all the dimensions in that .designer file, including the `AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);`.
- Do NOT use Anchor `Right` or `Bottom` anchored to a UserControl... its
  positioning will not auto-scale; instead, drop a Panel or other
  container into your UserControl and Anchor your other Controls to
  that Panel; have the Panel use Dock `Right`, `Bottom`, or `Fill` in your
  UserControl.
- Only the controls in the Controls lists when `ResumeLayout` at the end
  of `InitializeComponent` is called will be auto-scaled... if you
  dynamically add controls, then you need to `SuspendLayout();`
  `AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);` `AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;`
  `ResumeLayout();` on that control before you add it in.  And your
  positioning will also need to be adjusted if you are not using Dock
  modes or a Layout Manager like `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`.
- Base classes derived from `ContainerControl` should leave `AutoScaleMode` set to `Inherit` (the default value set in class `ContainerControl`; but NOT the default set by the designer). If you set it to anything else, and then your derived class tries to set it to Font (as it should), then the act of setting that to `Font` will clear out the designer's setting of `AutoScaleDimensions`, resulting in actually toggling off auto-scaling!  (This guideline combined with the prior one means you can never instantiate base classes in a designer... all classes need to either be designed as base classes or as leaf classes!)
- Avoid using `Form.MaxSize` statically / in the Designer. `MinSize` and `MaxSize` on Form do not scale as much as everything else. So, if you do all your work in 96dpi, then when at higher DPI your `MinSize` won't cause problems, but may not be as restrictive as you expected, but your `MaxSize` may limit your Size's scaling, which can cause problems. If you want `MinSize == Size == MaxSize`, don't do that in the Designer... do that in your constructor or `OnLoad` override... set both `MinSize` and `MaxSize` to your properly-scaled Size.
- All of the Controls on a particular `Panel` or `Container` should either use Anchoring or Docking. If you mix them, the auto-scaling done by that `Panel` will often misbehave in subtle bizarre ways.
- When it does its auto-scaling, it will be trying to scale the overall Form... however, if in that process it runs into the upper limit of the screen size, that is a hard limit that can then screw up (clip) the scaling.  Therefore, you should make sure all Forms in the Designer at 100%/96dpi are sized no larger than 1024x720 (which corresponds to 150% on a 1080p screen or 300% which is the Windows recommended value on a 4K screen).  But you need to subtract out for the giant Win10 title/caption bar... so more like 1000x680 max Size... which in the designer will be like 994x642 ClientSize.  (So, you can do a FindAll References on ClientSize to find violators.)

Comment: `NumericUpDown` doesn't scale its `Margin` properly, too. It seems the margin is scaled twice. If I scale it back once, it looks good.

Comment: `AutoScaleMode = Font` doesn't work well for users who use a very large font and with on Ubuntu. We prefer `AutoScaleMode = DPI`

Comment: > TextBox with MultiLine = True and Font inherited. 

Going crazy all day - that was the fix! Thanks so much! By the way, the same fix is also the fix for ListBox controls. :D

Comment: For me, list boxes with inherited font don't scale well. They do after explicitly set. (.NET 4.7)

Comment: In   [this reddit thread dealing with winform scaling problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/6m7p7w/windows_form_scaling_problem/) i found this link [to a Telerik Demo Monitor DPI Sample](http://www.telerik.com/docs/default-source/blogs-docs/telerikpermonitordpisamplecs-zip=) disclaimer i have not used it myself. This [Telerik article is about scaling dpi settings](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-)

Comment: Here's a way you can use the designer on machines with different DPI and font settings and not have the designer mess up all the sizes and positions: http://www.sgrottel.de/?p=1581&lang=en I tested it and it works.

Comment: On Windows 10 with a 4K monitor on .NET 4.6.1, it was necessary to add the application manifest and uncomment the relevant OS and DPI awareness sections or else the CurrentAutoScaleDimensions was always equal to the design ones and no autoscaling happened.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!
Only a minor correction: isn't 150% on 1920x1080 more like 1280x720 (instead of your 1024x720)? Accordingly, the final client size would result in 1252x642, no?

Answer (score 30):

My experience has been fairly different to the current top voted answer. By stepping through the .NET framework code and perusing the reference source code, I concluded that everything is in place for auto-scaling to work, and there was only a subtle issue somewhere messing it up. This turned out to be true.

If you create a properly reflowable / auto-sized layout, then almost everything works exactly like it should, automatically, with the default settings used by Visual Studio (namely, AutoSizeMode = Font on the parent form, and Inherit on everything else).

The only gotcha is if you have set the Font property on the form in the designer. The generated code will sort the assignments alphabetically, which means that `AutoScaleDimensions` will be assigned *before* `Font`. Unfortunately, this completely breaks WinForms auto scaling logic.

The fix is simple though. Either don't set the `Font` property in the designer at all (set it in your form constructor), or manually reorder these assignments (but then you have to keep doing this every time you edit the form in the designer). Voila, nearly perfect and fully automatic scaling with minimal hassle. Even the form sizes are scaled correctly.

---

I will list known problems here as I encounter them:

- Nested `TableLayoutPanel` [calculates control margins incorrectly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3044516/nested-tablelayoutpanel-is-displayed-with-large-empty-spaces-in-a-windows-forms-application-on-high-dpi-monitors). No known work-around short of avoiding margins and paddings altogether - or avoiding nested table layout panels.

Comment: Re not setting `Font` in designer:  A thought comes to mind:  go ahead and set the font in the designer, so that you can design with the desired font. THEN in constructor, after layout, read that font property and set same value back again?  Or maybe just ask layout to be done again?  [Caveat: I haven't had reason to test this approach.]  Or per [Knowleech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41261323/199364), in designer specify in **pixels** (so Visual Studio designer won't rescale on high DPI monitor), and in code read that value, convert from pixels to points (to get correct scaling).

Comment: Every single bit of our code has the auto scale dimensions set right before the auto scale mode and it all scales perfectly.  Seems like the order doesn't matter in most cases.

Comment: I searched my code for instances where `AutoScaleDimensions` was not set to the `new SizeF(6F, 13F)` as recommended in the top answer. It turned out that in every instance, the form's Font property had been set (not default). It appears that when `AutoScaleMode = Font`, then `AutoScaleDimensions` is calculated based on the form's font property. Also, the **Scaling** setting in the **Windows Control Panel** seems to have an affect on `AutoScaleDimensions`.

Answer (score 27):

Target your Application for .Net Framework 4.7 and run it under Windows 10 v1703 (Creators Update Build 15063). With [.Net 4.7 under Windows 10 (v1703), MS made a lot of DPI improvements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt799789(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.7, Windows Forms includes
>   enhancements for common high DPI and dynamic DPI scenarios. These
>   include:
>
> - Improvements in the scaling and layout of a number of Windows Forms controls, such as the MonthCalendar control and the
>     CheckedListBox control.
> - Single-pass scaling. In the .NET Framework 4.6 and earlier versions, scaling was performed through multiple passes, which caused
>     some controls to be scaled more than was necessary.
> - Support for dynamic DPI scenarios in which the user changes the DPI or scale factor after a Windows Forms application has been
>     launched.

To support it, add an application manifest to your application and signal that your app supports Windows 10:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.comn:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
        <!-- Windows 10 compatibility -->
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
    </application>
</compatibility>
```

Next, add an `app.config` and declare the app Per Monitor Aware. **This is NOW done in app.config and NOT in the manifest like before!**

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
   <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```

This [PerMonitorV2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt791579(v=vs.85).aspx) is new since Windows 10 Creators Update:

**DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2**

> Also known as Per Monitor v2. An advancement over the original
>   per-monitor DPI awareness mode, which enables applications to access
>   new DPI-related scaling behaviors on a per top-level window basis.
>
> - **Child window DPI change notifications** - In Per Monitor v2 contexts, the entire window tree is notified of any DPI changes that
>     occur.
> - **Scaling of non-client area** - All windows will automatically have their non-client area drawn in a DPI sensitive fashion. Calls to
>     EnableNonClientDpiScaling are unnecessary.
> - S**caling of Win32 menus** - All NTUSER menus created in Per Monitor v2 contexts will be scaling in a per-monitor fashion.
> - **Dialog Scaling** - Win32 dialogs created in Per Monitor v2 contexts will automatically respond to DPI changes.
> - **Improved scaling of comctl32 controls** - Various comctl32 controls have improved DPI scaling behavior in Per Monitor v2
>     contexts.
> - **Improved theming behavior** - UxTheme handles opened in the context of a Per Monitor v2 window will operate in terms of the DPI
>     associated with that window.

Now you can subscribe to 3 new events to get notified about DPI changes:

> - **Control.DpiChangedAfterParent**, which is fired Occurs when the DPI setting for a control is changed programmatically after a DPI
>     change event for it's parent control or form has occurred.
> - **Control.DpiChangedBeforeParent**, which is fired when the DPI setting for a control is changed programmatically before a DPI change
>     event for its parent control or form has occurred.
> - **Form.DpiChanged**, which is fired when the DPI setting changes on the display device where the form is currently displayed.

You also have 3 helper methods about DPI handling/scaling:

- **Control.LogicalToDeviceUnits**, which converts a value from logical to device pixels.
- **Control.ScaleBitmapLogicalToDevice**, which scales a bitmap image to the logical DPI for a device.
- **Control.DeviceDpi**, which returns the DPI for the current device.

If you still see issues, you can [opt-out of the DPI improvements via app.config entries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt492940(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you don't have access to source code, you can go to application properties in Windows Explorer, go to compatibility and select `System (Enhanced)`

[image]

which activates GDI scaling to also improve DPI handling:

> For applications that are GDI-based Windows can now DPI scale these on
>   a per-monitor basis. This means that these applications will,
>   magically, become per-monitor DPI aware.

Do all those steps and you should get a better DPI experience for WinForms applications. But remember, you need to target your app for .net 4.7 and need at least Windows 10 Build 15063 (Creators Update). In next Windows 10 Update 1709, we might get more improvements.

Answer (score 13):

A guide I wrote at work:

> WPF works in 'device independent units' which means all controls scale
>   perfectly to high dpi screens. In WinForms, it takes more care.
>
> WinForms works in pixels. Text will be scaled according to the system dpi but it will often be cropped by an unscaled control. To avoid such problems, you must eschew explicit sizing and positioning. Follow these rules:
>
> 1. Wherever you find it (labels, buttons, panels) set the AutoSize property to True.
> 2. For layout, use FlowLayoutPanel (a la WPF StackPanel) and TableLayoutPanel (a la WPF Grid) for layout, rather than vanilla
>      Panel.
> 3. If you are developing on a high dpi machine, the Visual Studio designer can be a frustration. When you set AutoSize=True, it will resize the control to your screen. If the control has AutoSizeMode=GrowOnly, it will remain this size for people on normal dpi, ie. be bigger than expected. To fix this, open the designer on a computer with normal dpi and do right-click, reset.

Comment: for dialogs that can be resized AutoSize on everything would be a nightmare, I don't want my buttons getting bigger and smaller as I increase my dialogs size manually while running the program.

Answer (score 10):

I found it to be very hard to get WinForms to play nice with high DPI.  So, I wrote a VB.NET method to override the form behavior:

```vb
Public Shared Sub ScaleForm(WindowsForm As System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    Using g As System.Drawing.Graphics = WindowsForm.CreateGraphics
        Dim sngScaleFactor As Single = 1
        Dim sngFontFactor As Single = 1
        If g.DpiX > 96 Then
            sngScaleFactor = g.DpiX / 96
            'sngFontFactor = 96 / g.DpiY
        End If
        If WindowsForm.AutoScaleDimensions = WindowsForm.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions Then
            'ucWindowsFormHost.ScaleControl(WindowsForm, sngFontFactor)
            WindowsForm.Scale(sngScaleFactor)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently came across this problem, especially in combination with Visual Studio rescaling when the editor is opened on high-dpi system. I found it best to **keep** `AutoScaleMode = Font`, but to set the Forms **Font** to the default font, but **specifying the size in pixel**, not point, i.e.: `Font = MS Sans; 11px`. In code, I **then** reset the font to the default: `Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont` and all is fine.

Just my two cents. I thought I share, because *“keeping AutoScaleMode=Font”*, and *“Set font size in pixel for the Designer”* was something I did not find on the internet.

I have some more details on my Blog: http://www.sgrottel.de/?p=1581&lang=en

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the anchors not working very well: I would go a step farther and say that exact positioning (aka, using the Location property) does not work very well with the font scaling. I've had to address this issue in two different projects. In both of them, we had to convert the positioning of all the WinForms controls to using the TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel. Using the Dock (usually set to Fill) property inside the TableLayoutPanel works very well and scales fine with the system font DPI.

Answer (score 3):

I had to go through and fix scaling on a whole bunch of WinForms programs, at least 20 of them, written by different people in different styles.  Lots of user controls, splitters, anchors, docking, panels, custom controls, dynamic layout code, etc.  It took a lot of experimenting, but I think I've come up with a good way of handling it.

This answer is what got me started in the right direction:  [Trying to make WinForms look good in 4K but forms too large after using AutoScaleMode.Dpi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893579/trying-to-make-winforms-look-good-in-4k-but-forms-too-large-after-using-autoscal)

The problem is the LayoutManager tends to mangle the layout if you have anything slightly complicated.  It's really a problem with calling SuspendLayout() and then doing stuff and then ResumeLayout().  (This also plays havoc with anchors when you mix user controls with TabControl.  But that's a separate issue.)

The key is to move the AutoScaleDimension and AutoScaleMode properties on the form outside of the SuspendLayout()/ResumeLayout(), so everything will be properly laid out before it scales.  Since the form designer orders statements however it wants to, just remove those two lines from the .Designer.cs file, and move them to right after the InitializeComponent() method in the constructor.

The other important part is to set all your user controls AutoScaleMode to Inherit, not font.  That way everything gets scaled all at once instead of doing a scale in the user control, and then rescaling stuff when it's added to the form.

Before changing AutoScaleMode on the form, I visit all the controls recursively, and anything which isn't docked and has an anchor other than Top|Left, I temporarily set the anchor to Top|Left, and then restore it back to its original value after setting AutoScaleMode.

Doing those three things gets me about 90% of the way, and almost everything works automagically.  Together, these 3 things ensure that everything is scaled one time, all together, and to the same proportions.  Any deviation from this pattern seems to lead to chaos in the layout.

It's also a good idea to PInvoke user32.dll SetProcessDPIAware() at the beginning of the application.  This seems to allow programmatic scaling to work even at 150%.  I haven't had any luck making it behave properly when setting SetProcessDpiAwareness() or SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(), they both seem to lead to layout chaos no matter what I do.