# Visual Studio 2013 - why is the resolution of my program changing?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a program, just for testing purposes, so I can learn to scale applications properly.
I just can't get the resolution to translate well to other devices.
So I'm making the program on a computer, which scaling is set to 100%. When I open the program on my smaller computer, which scaling is set to 150%, the controls gets bigger and the resolution is poor. I've tried all the different AutoScaleModes, even tried setting it to "None", but it did not seem to change a thing.

So is it not the scaling that's my problem? Or is it just Windows that's still a bit buggy with the 150% scale?

Comment: See this thread for info on winforms scaling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735174/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-auto-scales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't really get anything out of it, however, I found something that worked perfect for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/winforms-high-dpi-blurry-fonts