# The resolution of my forms changes when changing PC (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have made my VB.NET program installer, the operations with the database works very well, but a new problem presented:

On the computer where I developed the program, resolutions of my forms are excellent as I set, I install the same program on another computer in my house... and this happends

[image: resolution problems]

The image on the left , is the computer where I Tested... And the image on the right, is the computed where i develop the program.

I cant see the "Hide window" button on the left... (All forms of my program have this issue)

How I can fix this? :O

Comment: This can help: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/29766847/1565525](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29766847/1565525)

Comment: Set the controls' `Anchor` properties according to their placement. I.e. if the control (like your button) is placed in the bottom center you set it's anchor to `Bottom` only. **[A small article about it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2231/Working-with-Anchoring-and-Docking-Properties)**.

Comment: Are you sure you mean resolution (dpi) and not merely size? Are you simply creating fixed-size forms that are too big for the screen-size of the other machine?

Comment: I Just want my winforms size fit on different screens or monitors :/

Comment: Dock everything on your form. Don't just put controls on a bare form. Put them in panels and dock those panels to the top, bottom, left, right and fill. This will solve your layout and screen resolution problems. I look at your form and see 7 panels: 2 bottom each stacked on each other and 1 top fill. Inside the top fill: 1 left and 1 right fill. Inside the left, 1 bottom and 1 top fill. If you want to go further...which I do in my programs...I dock most individual controls in each panel too. Once you get in the habit of doing it, trust me, it takes no time and saves you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem, was playing with the dock property! Thank you Chase Rocker for your help.

http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/anchoring-and-docking-in-visual-basic-.net