# Identical fonts don't look identical on high DPI monitors

Tags: winforms, dpi

I've got a WinForms application that works great on older systems, but I'm having trouble making it look good on 4k monitors.  There are multiple issues, and a lot written on the subject, but this question is focused on one specific problem.  I can set different controls to use the same font, but on high DPI systems, the controls will look a lot different.  How can I fix this?

Obviously I can change the font size, move controls around, etc.  But Windows is adding a mysterious factor into my font sizes.  Without knowing what Windows is doing, it's hard for me to undo it!

On an older system my test window looks perfect:

[image: All controls have the same font size.]

On a high DPI system, some controls have a different font size than others:

[image: Requested font size does not match visible font size.]

I've tried several things, including manually setting the font on some controls rather than inheriting from the form.  As you can see, changing the font did not fix the problem:

[image]

After searching the Internet I've tried several things to fix this including:

- Changing the application between PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE, PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE, and [PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280512(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Explicitly [changing the font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735174/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-auto-scales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings#29766847) rather than using the form's font.
- Building on an old system vs building on a high DPI system.
- Building on a monitor set to 96 DPI / 100% vs building on a monitor set to 192 DPI / 200% on the same computer.
- Building the form in visual studio's designer vs building it in pure C# code.
- .Net 4.0 vs. .Net 4.6.1
- Visual Studio 2010 vs Visual Studio 2015

I only found one thing that fixed my problem.  Unfortunately I had to do it on the target machine, not on the machine where I'm building this.  So it's not a practical solution.  See the second item under "steps to repeat" for more details.

Steps to repeat:

- This happens with a lot of controls on a lot of forms.  See the code sample below for a small, simple demo.  That's how I got the screenshots, above.
- I can make this problem appear or disappear with one system setting.  If you change the main monitor to 96 DPI / 100% scaling, **then reboot**, you'll get the good result where all fonts are as requested.  If you change the main monitor to a different DPI setting, **then reboot**, you'll see the bad results.

  ```
  private void newFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Font copyOfFont = new Font(Font, FontStyle.Strikeout);
      Form form = new Form();
      form.Font = Font;
      string sample = "Abc 123 :)";
      int padding = 6;
      Label label = new Label();
      label.Text = sample;
      label.Top = padding;
      label.Left = padding;
      label.Font = copyOfFont;
      label.Parent = form;
      Button button = new Button();
      button.Text = sample;
      button.Top = label.Bottom + padding;
      button.Left = padding;
      button.Width = label.Width + padding * 2;
      button.Height = label.Height + padding * 2;
      button.Parent = form;
      TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
      textBox.Text = sample;
      textBox.Size = button.Size;
      textBox.Top = button.Bottom + padding;
      textBox.Left = padding;
      textBox.Parent = form;
      ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
      listBox.Items.Add(sample);
      listBox.Items.Add(sample);
      listBox.Width = button.Width;
      listBox.Height = button.Height * 2;
      listBox.Top = textBox.Bottom + padding;
      listBox.Left = padding;
      listBox.Font = copyOfFont;
      listBox.Parent = form;
      form.Show();
  }
  ```

Comment: Are you referring to the font size being different in the text box compared to the label in the HiDPI example?

Comment: Yes, the text box and the list box have one font size, and the button and the label have a different font size.  They should all have the same size.

Answer (score 2):

This is crazy but it works.

Everything I've seen on the internet about DPI Virtualization says that Windows will automatically set a process to PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE by default.  So unless you explicitly pick one of the other two settings, your application should look decent on a high resolution monitor.  It might be a little fuzzy, but it shouldn't look as bad as the examples I've shown above.

Apparently that's **not** true.  The default depends on the computer, and it depends on the day.  My solution:  **Explicitly** set the application to use PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE.  I've included a code sample below.

Note that you should be able to take care of this using the manifest.  Some sources say that's the preferred way, rather than using C# code.  We've had mixed results with that.  The C# code option seems more reliable.

```
    [DllImport("shcore.dll")]
    static extern int SetProcessDpiAwareness(_Process_DPI_Awareness value);

    enum _Process_DPI_Awareness
    {
        Process_DPI_Unaware = 0,
        Process_System_DPI_Aware = 1,
        Process_Per_Monitor_DPI_Aware = 2
    }


    public MainForm()
    {

        //int result = SetProcessDpiAwareness(_Process_DPI_Awareness.Process_System_DPI_Aware);
        //int result = SetProcessDpiAwareness(_Process_DPI_Awareness.Process_Per_Monitor_DPI_Aware);
        int result = SetProcessDpiAwareness(_Process_DPI_Awareness.Process_DPI_Unaware);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(result == 0);
```

This works on a number of different developer machines.  We're about to start sending the fix out to beta testers.

**Summary**

1. The O/S provides a compatibility mode for old programs running on high DPI systems.
2. WinForms and the O/S provide tools for manually changing the sizes of your controls depending on the DPI of the system
   or the current monitor.
3. Both #1 and #2 are both seriously buggy!
4. The details var a lot from one computer to the next.
5. Fixing #2 would be the more
       powerful option, but as far as I can tell it would be impossible to
       fix that.
6. Instead I fixed #1.  That works reasonably well.