# WinForms window changes dimensions when it encounters an async call

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, scaling, highdpi

I have a WinForms project which is several years old and has been retro-fitted with async event-handlers:

```
private async void dgvNewOrders_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

Inside this method is an async call:

```
var projectTemplate = await GetProjectTemplateFile(companyId, sourceLang, targetLang);
```

When the program runs on a normal resolution screen, it runs as expected. However, when run on a high-DPI screen the window's dimensions - as well as those of all child controls - jump to half-size as soon as it encounters that inner async call. It's as if the program is suddenly run in a compatibility mode or the scaling has been disabled.

Currently, in an effort to debug the problem, the `GetProjectTemplateFile` method consists simply of

```
private async Task<ProjectTemplateFile> GetProjectTemplateFile(long companyId, string sourceLanguage, string targetLanguage)
{
    return null;
}
```

It makes no difference whether `GetProjectTemplateFile` performs an async operation or not.

If I comment-out that async call to `GetProjectTemplateFile` then the program runs as expected without any jump in dimensions, even though there are still other async calls made in the `CellClick` event.

I've tried appending `.ConfigureAwait(true)` to the async call, which makes no difference. Nor does running the call synchronously with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Can anyone explain why the window's dimensions are changing with this particular  async call, and/or how to prevent this from happening?

**Update**
As per a request, here is a code sample which elicits the explained behaviour. There's nothing unusual happening here that I can see but I assure you, this very code is causing the explained behaviour.

```
private async void dgvNewOrders_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await _templateInteraction.GetProjectTemplateFile(1,
                                                                   "en-US",
                                                                   "de-CH");
    return;
}

public class TemplateInteraction : ITemplateInteraction
{
    public async Task<ProjectTemplateFile> GetProjectTemplateFile(long companyId, string sourceLanguage, string targetLanguage)
    {
        return null;

        // elided code
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Some other information which might be relevant:

- The `FormBorderStyle` of the window is "FixedToolWindow"
- The window is given an explicit width in a startup method
- `AutoSize` = False
- `AutoSizeMode` = GrowOnly
- The computer which it's being developed on does not have the Windows 10 1703 
  (Creator's) update which has new scaling logic
- If the `GetprojectTemplateFile` method is **not** async, *i.e.* has signature `public ProjectTemplateFile GetProjecttemplateFile(...)` then there is no problem. This problem appears to exist only when the method call is async - even if I make it a blocking call.

**UPDATE 2:**
I've found the specific line(s) of code which cause this problem:

```
MessageBox.Show(...);
```

The inner async call, `GetProjectTemplateFile`, calls an API and then checks the response:

```
var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(uri);
if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    MessageBox.Show(...);
    return null;
}
```

If I comment-out the `MessageBox.Show(...)` call then everything is normal, no scaling problems, no jump in dimensions.

But the problem occurs when the `MessageBox.Show(...)` call is in-place.

Furthermore, the API responds with a 200 (OK) so the MessageBox code isn't even being used. My guess is that the JIT compiler sees it as a possibility so... it re-renders the form?

Also, importantly, this code is not in the form's code-behind, it's in a class which the form is given an instance of in its constructor.

Comment: Please post a complete and minimal sample that will recreate the behavior you are seeing. Include anything that may be relevant, what framework you're using, os etc. If `async` is truly randomly changing the size of a form it would _interesting_ to investigate to say the least.

Comment: Thank you for the update but I cannot reproduce what you're seeing. Here is the code I'm using: [dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Sn4cj)

Comment: Even with .NET 4.6?

Comment: Tried 4.5.2, 4.6, & 4.6.1

Comment: Well... I appreciate that you took the time @JSteward. Maybe I'll see if I can upload a very short video somewhere showing this happening with the code also in shot.

Comment: Just to prove I'm not going mad, here's a video showing the behaviour and the relevant (insofar as I can see) code: https://www.screencast.com/t/kIaNsCILj8g

Comment: @awj, could you upload a minimal but complete WinForms project showing this behavior? I have Win10 v1703 and a high-DPI screen and I'd try to repro.

Comment: target your project to [.net 4.7 and run it on Win10 v1703 (Creators Update)to get DPI improvements for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43808350/1466046)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are using MessageBox from System.Windows namespace, referenced from PresentationFramework.dll, instead of System.Windows.Forms namespace?

```
// Causes DPI scaling problems:
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show() // loads WPF version from PresentationFramework.dll

// no DPI scaling issues:
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show() // uses standard winforms messagebox
```

So try using the standard MessageBox instead.

I've found that whenever any WPF-targeted dll gets loaded into memory, the DPI autoscaling gets reset. The specific function doesn't even need to be actually called - the dll's are loaded as soon as the parent function is called.

I had same problem by just having System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(), which loaded PresentationCore.dll. Thought I was going mad as well...

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, I found this out several months ago but never updated the OP.

Comment: If you need to use PresentationCore or PresentationFramework and this an issue, you can add this to your AssemblyInfo.cs file to avoid the reset when loading a type from these libraries: `[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]`