# Winforms overlapping list items and controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using C# and WinForms for a project but my controls and the items from my CheckedListBox overlap.

[image]

I think it has something to do with AutoScaling. Using Font autoscaling makes it look like the image attached, using DPI autoscaling fixes the overlapping controls but doesn't change the CheckedListBox overlap.

Comment: Have a read of this and ensure you're following the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735174/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-auto-scales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in Equalsk's link.

I installed .NET 4.7.1 (4.7 would be fine too) and added the following to my app.config.

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
   <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```