# Label size to be grows based on the screen resolution c# winform

Tags: winforms

I am developing one standalone tool in winforms using C#, in which I want the labels to be grows based on the screen resolution.

Kindly help me with the solution.

Comment: Try using WPF....WPF's xaml allows for easily creating scaleable views....Winforms is a bit outdated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write WinForms code that auto-scales to system font and dpi settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735174/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-auto-scales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings)

Comment: It is pretty difficult to mess this up, the form's AutoScaleMode property takes care of it.  It has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution for this question.

```
 private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, this.Width / 100);//you can set the font size yourself
}
```