# Adapt combobox to work on scale

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a software in c# using Microsft Visual Studio 2017 where I have some comboboxes in it.
Everything works correctly regardless of the screen resolution but, when I set a different scale from 100% all the comboboxes show very small.

[image: Changing scale on Windows]

See pictures below to better understanding:

**100% Scale:**

[image]

**175% Scale:**
[image]

As you can see, combobox looks smaller as much as I get a bigger scale factor in my Windows configuration.
How can I  maintain the same size ratio when I change the scale?

These are the settings that I have for my comboBox:
[image]

And this are the settings of my form:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Edit you `app.manifest` (add one if, for some reasons, is missing in your Project). The usual link: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top). And some advices/experience sharing: [How to write WinForms code that auto-scales to system font and dpi settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735174/how-to-write-winforms-code-that-auto-scales-to-system-font-and-dpi-settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way that "solved" the problem.
After creating the .exe file, I make right click and select **Properties**:

After that, select **Compatibility** and set this configuration (I'm sorry, my SO is in spanish):

[image]

After setting this, Windows will rescale correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the Forms properties to

- AutoSize = True
- AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink

( I've also seen that in combination with these settings above the AutoScaleMode was set to "None" before it actually worked)

Can you give that a try?