# Why does visual studio 2017 changes size of user controls when other users opens my solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Today we got the following problem. Our solution has a winforms form sized 1300, 500 pixels. There are also some big buttons sized 240, 65 pixels.

Another developer of the team pulled the solution and noticed that the style of the program is slightly different. Now, the form is 1730, 500 pixels sized and the buttons are 319, 72 pixels sized.

Any idea what this is caused of?

We never had issues like that before in our team.

Comment: It means that the Form scales on Font and the Font size in the other machine is scaled to 130%. Visual Studio pops a warning (kind of) about this, asking to switch to *standard* scaling.

Comment: Probably it's dpi-related. What is the `AutoScaleMode` value of said (all?) form? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22735174/1997232) is a big topic.